# how to make country dropdown with search box in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, dropdown-attribute, customer-address-attribute

How can i add search input on country drop dawn field in magento
i need to add the search input like show in below screenshoot
[image]

Comment: Where do you need to add this field? Which form?

Comment: checkout address field

Answer (score 0):

Override the **product_form.xml** into your custom module and add below code, it maybe render where you want but you will figure it out

```
<field name="custom_test_field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Address\Column\Countries</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Test Field</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_test_field</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
            </item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```